# Hadith of Abu Lahab's Punishment Lightened on Mondays

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Some people claim that Abu Lahab's punishment in Hellfire will be lightened. This is an exact statement which I found online while reading tafseer of Surah Lahab (Surah Masad):

> The hadith of Abu Lahab's punishment being eased in Jahanam on Mondays for celebrating the Birth of the Prophet SAWAWS is very well known and is Sahih.  You may find it in Sahih Bukhari and other Hadith books.

I did not find this on [sunnah.com](http://www.sunnah.com), so I have some doubt about this. I would like to know:

- The exact text of this hadith
- The ruling on it (mawdoo' vs. da'eef vs. hassan vs. sunnah)
- Which books and collections it's found in
- Any statements of scholars on it

Comment: If anyone wants to see this Hadith from Islam360 App, it is Hadith No. 5101 there.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/39) is the hadith in question:

> **Narrated Um Habiba:**
> (daughter of Abu Sufyan) I said, "O Allah's
> Messenger (ﷺ)! Marry my sister. the daughter of Abu Sufyan." The
> Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Do you like that?" I replied, "Yes, for even now I
> am not your only wife and I like that my sister should share the good
> with me." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "But that is not lawful for me." I
> said, We have heard that you want to marry the daughter of Abu
> Salama." He said, "(You mean) the daughter of Um Salama?" I said,
> "Yes." He said, "Even if she were not my step-daughter, she would be
> unlawful for me to marry as she is my foster niece. I and Abu Salama
> were suckled by Thuwaiba. So you should not present to me your
> daughters or your sisters (in marriage)." Narrated 'Urwa: Thuwaiba was
> the freed slave girl of Abu Lahb whom he had manumitted, and then she
> suckled the Prophet. When Abu Lahb died, one of his relatives saw him
> in a dream in a very bad state and asked him, "What have you
> encountered?" Abu Lahb said, "I have not found any rest since I left
> you, except that I have been given water to drink in this (the space
> between his thumb and other fingers) and that is because of my
> manumitting Thuwaiba."

Some scholars have interpreted this hadith to say that Abu Lahab's torment was being relieved for the occasion of the Prophet's birth (which supports the validity of celebrating the birthday of the Prophet), others relate the relief to his action in manumitting (freeing) the slave girl Thuwaiba.

Answer (score 0):

From Ibn `Abbas said, when verse comes down ,

> "And warn your relatives to the nearest "(Surah Ash-Syu'araa [26]:
>   214), and those who are sincere of your tribes, Rasulullah SAW
>   straight out to the  Safa hill, then shouted, "Yes Shabaahaah!" (call
>   to gather in the morning). They wonder, "Who is this screaming?" They
>   replied, 'Muhammad.' They were soon gathered to him. Rasulullah SAW
>   called (again), "O Bani so and so, O Bani so and so, O Bani Abdi
>   Manaaf, O Children of Abdul Muttalib!" Then gathered the people (of
>   the tribes mentioned earlier) to him. " Rasulullah SAW said (after
>   they get together) again, "What do you think, if I were to tell you
>   that a horse will come out at the top of this hill, what would you
>   justify me?" They replied, "We have not seen you lie." Rasulullah SAW
>   then said, "Know that I am the warner among a painful punishment." Abu
>   Lahab answered immediately, "Tabban laka (you ruined)! Is it just for
>   this you collect we?! "then he got up and left, then came down this
>   letter," perish the hands of Abu Lahab "and indeed he actually perish.

(Bukhari, no. 4589 and Muslim, no. 307, and the wording of this hadith belongs to Muslims )

About the 'monday' ..
Saheeh Bukhari juz VI page 125, Dar al-Fikr printed in 1401 H - 1981 M / 1/591, Maktabah syamilah

The story is that Abu Lahab so happy with the birth of the Rasulullah SAW (which turned out to be his mortal enemy) and jubilant at the time, until on that Monday Abu Lahab freed a slave named Tsuwaibah .. maybe that's why ..

Wallahu a'lam

Comment: My question is about a hadith which establishes that Abu Lahab's punishment in Hellfire will be lightened on Mondays, which doesn't seem to be what your answer is about.

Comment: Sorry, missunderstood your question .. but I'll try to find out

Answer (score -1):

Yes according to Bukhari kitabu Nikkah, "A relative dreamt dt he saw Abu Lab being purnisd and askd him abt his condition since he left. Abu lab replied except only the day he freed his slave bcos of the birth of the prophet that he received water. By Alfahuja

Comment: Do you have a reference number for Kitaab an-Nikkah or a link?

Comment: The narration does not mention anything about the Prophets birth, and it was a dream by one of Abu Lahab's relatives; not an evidence.  It's in Kitab an-Nikah, Book 67, Hadith 39